# Cascading DropDownListFor ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I have a page with two drop downs (DropDownListFor) that are populated on load. One is a category and the other is the items that fit that category. There is a title (TextAreaFor) below that is updated to reflect the text in the second drop down.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BLL_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BLL_ID, Model.BLL_Categories, new { @style = "max-width: 500px;" })
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BLL_2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-6">    
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BLL_2, SessionManager.CurrentBLL.OriginalBLL, new { @style = "max-width: 500px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BLL_2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Note, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Note, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "3", @readonly = "true" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The first drop down has a change event registered in JS that populates the second drop down. The second drop down has a change event that updates the title.

```js
var categories = $("#BLL_ID");
var requests = $("#BLL_2");

$("#BLL_2").change(function () {
    updateTitle();
});

categories.change(function () {
    requests.find('option').remove();
    $.getJSON('_Some_Page', { Category: 
         $("#BLL_ID>option:selected").val() }, function (data) {
         $(data).each(function (index) {
                $("<option value=" + this.Value + ">" + this.Text + "
                       </option>").appendTo(requests);
         });
    });
    updateTitle();
});

function updateTitle() {
    var title = $("#BLL_2>option:selected").text();
    $("#Note").val(title);
}
```

The issue is regarding the title update during the first drop down change event. If I use the JS debugger, I notice that the second drop down is not populated yet when the updateTitle() function is called. Is there any way to wait until the drop down is populated to call the function?

Comment: try moving the updateTitle inside the getJSON (put it after the each and hopefully it will hit is sequentially and give the result you want.  Another less ideal option would be to put the update inside a delay and delay it

Comment: The updateTitle() function is already executing as written. The issue is that $("BLL_2>option:selected").text() returns a blank string. When using the debugger, the drop down list has not yet visibly updated when updateTitle() is called. I'm assuming that is why the selected statement returns a blank string. I keep reading about data binding but I'm not sure what that means. Do I have to wait until the data is bound to the drop down before trying to determine the selected item?

Comment: I think so, yes.  that is why I suggested moving it in the getJSON.  With it outside it is probably calling the getJSON and then calling your update before the get has finished.  I am hoping moving it inside will resolve the timing issue

Comment: Excellent call. Works just fine now. Thank you for the help. You should rewrite that as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that by putting calls inside they will be fired sequentially.  If they are outside then it will call the database and try to call the update before the database call has finished and will cause issues.  Try changing your code like this

```
categories.change(function () {
    requests.find('option').remove();
    $.getJSON('_Some_Page', { Category: 
         $("#BLL_ID>option:selected").val() }, function (data) {
             $(data).each(function (index) {
                $("<option value=" + this.Value + ">" + this.Text + "
                   </option>").appendTo(requests);
             });
         updateTitle(); //move the update here so it is inside the getJSON
    });
});
```